# Formatting text in Hero Card

Tags: botframework

I need to show formatted text in HeroCard

```
card = new HeroCard
            {
                Title = taskEntity.SourceEntityName + " : " + taskEntity.SourceEntityInstanceName,
                Subtitle = taskEntity.Description + " : " + $"{taskEntity.CreatedOn:D}",
                Text = await GetDetails(taskEntity),
                Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                {
                    new CardAction {Value = "Approve " + taskEntity.Id, Title = "Approve", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack},
                    new CardAction {Value = "Reject " + taskEntity.Id, Title = "Reject", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack}
                }
            };
```

GetDetails returns a formatted string with '\r\n' by using 'Environment.NewLine' in it so that each detail is on a new line but it doesn't work. Is there a way without using Adaptive Cards?

**Edit:**
1. The channel I am testing on is Skype

Comment: Which channel are you using when "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Doesn't work on Skype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `'\r\n'` please try `'\n\n'`.  In a Skype bot, you can also use `'<br/>'`

Here is an example of both:

```
if (length > 0 && activity.Text == "hero")
{
    var reply = ((Activity)context.Activity).CreateReply(string.Empty);
    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    var heroCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Text = "1)Hero Card Text\n\n2)next line!\n\n3)and another new line!"
        };
    reply.Attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());
    await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
else if (length > 0 && activity.Text == "hero html")
{
    var reply = ((Activity)context.Activity).CreateReply(string.Empty);
    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    var heroCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Text = "Hero Card Text <br/>next line!",
        };
    reply.Attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());
    await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
```

and the result in Skype:

[image]