# Formatting the Text in HeroCard

Tags: botframework

I am using Hero Card below to show the Details.

[image: Hero Card]

How can i put line breaks so that i get Hospital Name,Available Day, Session and Appointment No in seperate lines.

I read Some article where they say to use "\n\n". But its not working for me, also i have not published this is in any medium am still using the bot emulator.
Please Help. Thanking in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting text in Hero Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448407/formatting-text-in-hero-card)

Answer (score 2):

Try `<br/>`.

Or, if you want more special "form", read about markup syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The bot emulator (and web chat) formats some messages differently than other channels. For this reason you can use `\n\n` to declare a new line when testing out hero cards in the Emulator like so:

```
var card = new HeroCard
{
    Title = "Hero \n\n Title",
    Text = "More Words \n\n New Line \n\n New Line"
};
```

And you'll see the following result:

[image]

***The Emulator Does not work with HTML styling*** 
As shown by the following code sampple and picture

```
var card = new HeroCard
{
    Title = "Hero <br> Title",
    Text = "More Words <br> New Line <br> New Line <b><font color=\"#11b92f\">GREEN</font></b>"
};
```

[image]

***HTML Styling does work however in other channels like MS Teams*** 
Here is that same code output in MS Teams

[image]

### Summary

Use `\n\n` to create a new line in Hero & Thumbnail Cards while testing with the Bot Emulator or while using Web Chat. Switch to HTML styling when needed in other channels (I don't think MS Teams supports `\n\n` for creating new lines in Hero Cards for example).